# Cannot resolve ImportError

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, packaging

I have an import issue (circular import or import order error) that has gone undetected for a long time since it doesn't show up when installed with `pip install -e .` for development.

The package has several core operations defined in `microhapulator/op/`, a subcommand-based CLI defined in `microhapulator/cli/`, and some core modules defined in `microhapulator/*.py` (the current version of the code is available at https://github.com/bioforensics/MicroHapulator/tree/076094b73b8641268c423cbbe41a0cb5d00c7ec5). The problem seems to be that the `microhapulator.cli` and `microhapulator.op` subpackages are not being imported in the correct order or have some complex interdependence. With recently added debugging output I'm getting this when I try to run the program.

```
$ mhpl8r --help
Loading microhapulator
Loading microhapulator.parsers
Loading microhapulator.profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/standage/anaconda3/envs/mhtest/bin/mhpl8r", line 5, in <module>
    from microhapulator.cli import main
  File "/Users/standage/anaconda3/envs/mhtest/lib/python3.9/site-packages/microhapulator/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import op
ImportError: cannot import name 'op' from partially initialized module 'microhapulator' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/standage/anaconda3/envs/mhtest/lib/python3.9/site-packages/microhapulator/__init__.py)
```

I have done a thorough review of the code, the package structure, the modules, and the code, and I cannot figure out the source of the error. The [pycycle](https://github.com/bndr/pycycle) program doesn't find any circular imports. **What is the source of this error?**

---

Test environment setup:

```
conda create --name mhtest -y python=3.8
conda activate mhtest
git clone https://github.com/bioforensics/MicroHapulator.git
cd MicroHapulator/
git checkout 076094b73b
pip install .
```

Comment: Remove the imports in `microhapulator/__init__.py` where you just import a submodule relatively, the line causing the error `from . import op` for starters

Comment: Doesn't reproduce on a Linux and Python 3.8. Only culprits I can think of are the two modules [op/sim.py](https://github.com/bioforensics/MicroHapulator/blob/076094b73b8641268c423cbbe41a0cb5d00c7ec5/microhapulator/op/sim.py) and [op/type.py](https://github.com/bioforensics/MicroHapulator/blob/076094b73b8641268c423cbbe41a0cb5d00c7ec5/microhapulator/op/type.py). You can refactor those common classes/functions to a different subpackage

Comment: @edd Frustrating that it doesn't replicate. I originally discovered the issue when trying to configure continuous documentation builds on readthedocs. So I'm seeing it fail with python 3.8 and 3.9 on my Mac, and python 3.8 on the readthedocs Ubuntu 20.04 VM (latest build [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/microhapulator/builds/15639019/)).